# Find matching questions from all records

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, search, nlp

I've a library of questions and answers and building an API in NodeJS which allows to search for answers based on the question passed as input. Following is my goal:

1. Split the question by space
2. Tokenize it and remove stopwords
3. Query database for records where question contains one or more words from the tokenized array
4. Ideally sort in descending order total number of matches in the question. For eg: If the question A contains 'module' and 'solution' and question B contains only 'solution', then question A should be shown before question B

I've been able to achieve 1 to 3, using the below code:

```
let question = req.query.question;
let arrQuestions = question.split(" ");
let tokenizedQuestion = stopwords.removeStopwords(arrQuestions);

let whereClause = tokenizedQuestion.join("%' OR answer LIKE '%");
whereClause = " answer LIKE '%" + whereClause + "%' ";

let query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_libraries WHERE " + whereClause;
```

I'm not able to figure out how to achieve 4. Can somebody provide pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Full Text Search. Following is the stored procedure I created to enable searching:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_Search $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_Search`(IN QuestionToSearch TEXT, IN TagsToSearch TEXT, IN CollectionsToSearch TEXT, IN ReturnRecordsFromIndex INT, IN TotalRecordsToReturn INT)
BEGIN
    SET @MainQuery = CONCAT("SELECT *, MATCH(question, answer_content) AGAINST (", CONCAT("'", QuestionToSearch, "'"), " IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score ");
    SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " FROM tbl_libraries ");
    SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " WHERE MATCH(question, answer_content) AGAINST (", CONCAT("'", QuestionToSearch, "'"), " IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ");

    IF F_IsNullOrEmpty(TagsToSearch) AND NOT F_IsNullOrEmpty(CollectionsToSearch) THEN
        SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " AND collections LIKE '%", CollectionsToSearch, "%' ");
    ELSEIF F_IsNullOrEmpty(CollectionsToSearch) AND NOT F_IsNullOrEmpty(TagsToSearch) THEN
        SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " AND tags LIKE '", TagsToSearch, "' ");
    ELSEIF NOT F_IsNullOrEmpty(TagsToSearch) AND NOT F_IsNullOrEmpty(CollectionsToSearch) THEN
        SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " AND tags LIKE '", TagsToSearch, "' AND collections LIKE '", CollectionsToSearch, "' ");
    END IF;

    SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " ORDER BY score DESC ");
    SET @MainQuery = CONCAT(@MainQuery, " LIMIT ", ReturnRecordsFromIndex, ", ", TotalRecordsToReturn);

    PREPARE SqlQuery FROM @MainQuery;
    EXECUTE SqlQuery;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This uses a custom function I created `F_IsNullOrEmpty`, which is as shown below for completion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_IsNullOrEmpty(ValueToCheck VARCHAR(256)) RETURNS BOOL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    IF((ValueToCheck IS NULL) OR (LENGTH(ValueToCheck) = 0) OR (ValueToCheck = 'null')) THEN
        Return True;
    ELSE
        Return False;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you do not want to use MySQL fulltext search for this?

If the answer is some flavour of 'No', you can continue reading...

In one of my project I was implementing something like this.
Query wise it looks like this (simplified version):

```
SELECT
    name
FROM
    table
WHERE
    name REGEXP 'term1|term2|term3' -- you can use your OR + LIKE way
ORDER BY
    SP_TermsWeitght(name, 'term1 term2 term3') DESC
```

All the magic is in my SP_TermsWieght function that returns "weight" (number) and I'm supplying a list of terms (cleaned and normalized) to the function.

The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SP_TermsWeight`(
    `sValue` TEXT,
    `sTerms` VARCHAR(127)
)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE p INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE w INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE l INT;
    DECLARE c CHAR(1);
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(63);
    DECLARE delimiters VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT ' ,';

    SET sTerms = TRIM(sTerms);
    SET l = LENGTH(sTerms);

    IF (l > 0) THEN
        -- checking is value matched terms exactly
        IF (sTerms = sValue) THEN
            SET w = 50000;
        ELSE
            -- supposing that "the terms" is one single term so it it match in full, the weight will be high
            IF (l <= 63) THEN
                SET w = w + SP_TermWeight(sValue, sTerms, 5000, 1000, 100);
            END IF;
            -- not processing it term by term if it is already matched as full
            IF (w = 0) THEN
                -- processing term by term using space or comma as delimiter
                WHILE i <= l DO
                    BEGIN
                        SET c = SUBSTRING(sTerms, i, 1);
                        IF (LOCATE(c, delimiters) > 0) THEN
                            SET s = SUBSTRING(sTerms, p, i - p);
                            SET w = w + SP_TermWeight(sValue, s, 50, 10, 0);
                            SET p = i + 1;
                        END IF;
                        SET i = i + 1;
                    END;
                END WHILE;

                IF (p > 1 AND p < i) THEN
                    SET s = SUBSTRING(sTerms, p, i - 1);
                    SET w = w + SP_TermWeight(sValue, s, 50, 10, 0);
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN w;
END
```

Technically speaking it is 'separating' terms using delimiters and checking if the value "contains" the term.
It's a bit hard to explain everything what it does (I've added a few comments in the code for you).
Feel free to ask questions if you do not understand some bits.

In your case it can be simplified dramatically as you do not need to differentiate begin/end/middle matches.

Another helper function that used internally:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SP_TermWeight`(
    `sValue` TEXT,
    `sTerm` VARCHAR(63),
    `iWeightBegin` INT,
    `iWeightEnd` INT,
    `iWeightMiddle` INT
)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE r INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET sTerm = TRIM(sTerm);
    IF (LENGTH(sTerm) > 1) THEN
        IF (iWeightBegin != 0 AND sValue REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', sTerm)) THEN
            SET r = r + iWeightBegin;
        END IF;

        IF (iWeightEnd != 0 AND sValue REGEXP CONCAT(sTerm, '[[:>:]]')) THEN
            SET r = r + iWeightEnd;
        END IF;

        IF (r = 0 AND iWeightMiddle != 0 AND sValue REGEXP sTerm) THEN
            SET r = r + iWeightMiddle;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN r;
END
```

This function used for assigning different weights if the term matched to value from the beginning of the string, at the end of the string or in the middle. It is important in my case. In your case it might be simple LIKE.